# Clever way of evaluating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}} dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How would you spot a good substitution here?

Or perhaps there is a better way of solving it (i.e. without a substitution).

It is misleadingly (unless you can in fact arrive at useful result) attractive to factorize it: $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-t)^2-(t^2-1)}}dt$$ but the factorization does not seem to lead anywhere.

I shall not say what the substitution is that is used in the result in hope that there is a clever way of arriving at it that you will inform me of.

Comment: [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) provide a general method for evaluating integrals with quadratic surds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** When you differentiate $\sqrt{t}$ you obtain a root in the denominator. So, try to do the same with the term in the square root (differentiate with respect to $t$)
$$\left(\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}\right)'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}}(1-2xt+x^2)'=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}}$$ and $x$ is a constant.

Comment: This is actually quite good. The substitution that they have used is the one that Nizar has noted. But I was rather interested at how they figured out that that is the substitution necessary to be used. And your argument makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use the Change  of variable  $u=1-2xt+x^2$, then $du=-2xdt$. I think you can take it from here.

Indeed, since in the denomenator you have under redical  $t$ in degree one, so directly think about a linear change of variable , as its derivative would be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Notice here, $t$ is a variable & $x$ is a constant

Let $1-2xt+x^2=u\implies -2x\ dt=du$ or $dt=-\frac{du}{2x}$, hence
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}}\ dt\\
=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt t}\left(-\frac{du}{2x}\right)\\=-\frac{1}{2x}\int u^{-1/2}\ du\\
=-\frac{1}{2x}\frac{u^{1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}}+C\\
=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1-2xt+x^2}+C}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: Alright, could you please explain what is wrong ?

Comment: $t^{-1/2}$, not $t^{1/2}$.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your observation